# Transform XML document to base64 using XSLT 1

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, lxml

I need to transform an XML document into base64 using an XSLT 1 transformation.

I have tried to do this using this template: https://github.com/ilyakharlamov/xslt_base64

Here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:b64="https://github.com/ilyakharlamov/xslt_base64"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:include href="base64.xsl"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="b64:encode" >
            <xsl:with-param name="asciiString">
              <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works but it strips all the XML tags and only encodes the text. I need to actually encode everything (the whole document, as is). Changing the output method to XML does not help.

Comment: Why do you need XSLT if the task it to base64-encode an XML document? Use any library you have for base64 encoding files directly on the XML input document.

Comment: Hello @MartinHonnen, that is a great question... It is part of a bigger transform (which outputs a json object with a bunch of fields + one field `original` which should include the whole XML doc, encoded in base64 - *not my requirements, so not sure why this field is needed*). I simplified the xsl, just to ask this question without any unnecessary noise.

Comment: You would need to serialize the XML to a string, something XSLT 1 can also only do well if you write lots of code or use another library like the one by Evan Lenz, for instance.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Using Evan Lenz xml-to-string.xsl did it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Martin Honnen's comments, here is how I did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:b64="https://github.com/ilyakharlamov/xslt_base64"
  version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="xml-to-string.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:include href="base64.xsl"/>
  
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="b64:encode" >
            <xsl:with-param name="asciiString">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="xml-to-string" />
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

using this: http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/